# If I hash ABC123, where ABC123 appears five times inside the file, will each of the five instances of ABC123 appear as identical hash values?

Tags: hash

If I hash the word SOUND, where the word SOUND appears five times inside the file, will each of the five instances of SOUND appear as identical hash values?

Comment: Rather than waiting for someone else to answer, you could always try it and see what happens

Comment: This will be the first time I have personally attempted it. Not sure how to test.

Comment: There are [plenty of web sites](https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm) that will do this for you (obviously you would not use them if what you are hashing is supposed to remain secret, but that clearly doesn't apply here)

Comment: The question is ambiguous. We do not know if you hash the file, which gives a single hash; or several times the same thing, which will give several times the same hash.

Comment: Or if you are hashing the hash of a hash ... etc 5 times

Answer (score 1):

Hash functions are operating from $H:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^n$ where $n$ is the output size. So, if you hash a text file you will get only $n$-bit result.

Cryptographic Hash functions are deterministic same input same output and random functions in a sense the output is unpredictable. We don't expect a pattern in the output.

This output from an [online](http://www.sha1-online.com/) SHA-1  for 5-times SOUND

```
 fd8b11a88ea2ef299d4fec6608d4c48a9b6f535e
```

As you see, there is no pattern. And don't expect to see a pattern, too.